# curl_easy_perform doesn't wait for JSON input to be provided on a URL

Tags: json, http, libcurl

I have written the following code.

```
CURL *curl_handle;
  struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
  int ret;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://<url>");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);

  int httpCode(0);
  std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

According to my understanding, curl_easy_perform should wait on the  to get json as a resource to it. But unfortunately my program returns without waiting for the JSON resource.

I want libcurl to wait on the  for JSON resource and once it is available then only it should proceed further and process the data obtained.

Am I missing out something in my code or my understanding is incorrect?
Please help me progress further on this issue.

Comment: Your program issues a HTTP GET request and it (probably?) gets a response back. libcurl delivers the server response to you. It has no knowledge about any particular resource to wait for, JSON or otherwise. It's really not clear to us what you want your program to do that it doesn't already do...

Comment: The line `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);` sets a function called `writer` to be the callback for when a response is obtained from the server. This will only happen after sending the request via `curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);`. If the JSON resource is the response that you expect the server to return following the request, you can obtain it within the `writer` function when it is invoked.